# uiautomation recorded scripts save location

Tags: iphone, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I can't seem to figure out how to save recorded scripts in the "UI Automation" tool in Instruments.

I launch my iphone app with "Profile" select the "UI Automation" tool, add a "New Script" and start the script recording.  I click around and I can replay the script and watch the iPhone app behave correctly.

If I save the Instrument's trace file, it just has debug data but no Scripts.  How do you save those scripts and where do they end up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Scripts that are created in the automation tool and not exported exist as part of the saved Instruments trace document. Re-opening the trace document should list any scripts created.

You can export scripts as stand-alone .js files if you'd prefer by right-clicking on the script editor and choosing Export.

Comment: hah, did not think to right click and "export" but that's exactly what I'm looking for!  Thanks

Comment: Really helped!  @MyztikJenz